# how to set div max width in D3

Tags: d3.js

how can I set the max width of a div within d3?
I tried

```
svg.append('div')
                          .attr('class','chart')
                          .attr("max-width",div_width)
                          .attr("height",div_height)
```

but it doesn't do the trick, however, if I set it in a css style with the class, it works,

```
div.chart {
        margin : 2%;
        overflow: auto;
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3);
        max-width: 900px; // this works 
    }
```

I need the max width to be dynamic which is why I want to set it within d3.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it should be in (style) and as a string

```
svg.append('div')
   .attr('class','chart')
   .attr("max-width",div_width)
   .attr("height",div_height)
```

should change to

```
svg.append('div')
   .attr('class','chart')
   .style("max-width",div_width+'px')
   .attr("height",div_height)
```